# Is there any problem if I use get_template_part like this?

Tags: post-formats, get-template-part

I want to display different content on my home page and in single pages, so I am using the following code in `index.php`:

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-home', get_post_format() );
```

At first I am displaying `content-home.php`, then I will create new templates like `content-home-video.php` etc.

Will it cause any problems if I use `get_template_part()` like this?

Answer (score 0):

> Will it cause any problems if I use get_template_part() like this?

I can't really see any answer other than... no. But that's based on not knowing what you actually mean by "problems".

If you mean "is this code totally bulletproof no matter what scenario you could possible throw at it" then yes, it *may* cause problems - I don't think you can cover for *every* eventuality.

But if you mean "am I using the WordPress API in the manner intended/am I doing it right", then yes, you certainly are.